# Can I change Google Apps Script sandbox settings to allow an XMLHttpRequest to a non-SSL API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script

In a Google Apps Script script, I have a function displaying an HTTP sidebar.

I would like to populate this sidebar with data from an Intranet API, which is not SSL-enabled.

GAS blocks the query, requiring that the content be served over HTTPS.

As there is no real safety concern here since the API is only reachable from the company's intranet, considered safe, is there a way to bypass the built-in security, and allow an AJAX request to a non-safe server?

Comment: `bypass the built-in security` - I hope not!

Comment: obviously not. otherwise, what would be the point of the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can't.

The [IFRAME sandbox mode in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions) is based on the HTML5's iframe sandbox wherein the only allowed values are:

- allow-forms
- allow-modals
- allow-orientation-lock
- allow-pointer-lock
- allow-popups
- allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox
- allow-presentation
- allow-same-origin
- allow-scripts
- allow-top-navigation
- allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation